# nginx: [emerg] the size 10485760 of shared memory zone "limit" conflicts with already declared size 5242880

Tags: nginx

My server：centos7，openresty，php7

I followed this tutorial： https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000011299586

After I typed this command：

`/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -t`

error showed up：

> nginx: [emerg] the size 10485760 of shared memory zone "limit" conflicts with already declared size 52428800 in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:38 nginx: configuration file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed

How to  fix this issue? Where can I modify?

I executed these commands：

`vim /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

`/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -t`

Paste my  nginx.conf：

```
user www; worker_processes 1;

#error_log logs/error.log; #error_log logs/error.log notice; #error_log logs/error.log info;

#pid logs/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http { include mime.types; default_type application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;
#WAF

lua_shared_dict limit 50m;  #防 cc 使用字典，大小 50M
lua_shared_dict guard_dict 100m;
lua_shared_dict dict_captcha 70m;
lua_max_running_timers 1;
lua_package_path "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/waf/?.lua";
init_by_lua_file "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/waf/init.lua";
access_by_lua_file "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/waf/access.lua";
lua_shared_dict limit 10m;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
     #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring *lua_shared_dict* twice:

```
lua_shared_dict limit 50m;
lua_shared_dict limit 10m;
```